# How to trim uploaded file name's length to 10 chars when using Drupal CCK file fields?

Tags: php, drupal, file-upload, cck

I uploaded 1 file and name it "test-test-test-test-test.php".
It create problem in my layout.
my layout is mess up.
so if i upload file name up to 10 char then its fine.

Comment: Try to keep the title short and clean. Also, `drupal` is a unnecessary tag here.

Comment: As explained by dayana to some of the answers, [drupal] is indeed helpful.

Comment: yes its not core PHP as i used drupal and CCK file field its not possible using "substr" function.

Answer (score 1):

Rename it before uploading.

In PHP:

```
<?php
$filename = 'test-test-test-test-test.php';
rename($filename, substr($filename, 0, 10) . '.php'));
?>
```

Comment: its CCK file field in drupal.i cant do like this.bcoz when i click on node view it has to be full view but on home page display only its trimmed.

Comment: Then second option is yours. Trim filename as i wrote. Note: you'll need to take care about paths.

Answer (score 1):

**Single line solution**

```
<?
$filename="test.php";
$filename=str_pad(trim($filename), 10, "123456789", STR_PAD_LEFT);
echo $filename;
//12test.php
$filename="test.php";
$filename=str_pad(trim($filename), 14, "123456789", STR_PAD_LEFT);
echo $filename;
//123456test.php
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$filename = 'testtesttesttesttesttest.php'; 
$filename = basename($path, ".php");
$filename = substr($filename, 0, 10);
$filename .= '.php';
```

Comment: its CCK file field in drupal.i cant do like this.bcoz when i click on node view it has to be full view but on home page display only its trimmed.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution.
Its using jquery.

```
jQuery("div.files .view-content .views-field-field-file-file-fid  .filefield-file a")
  .each(function(){
    var file_text =  jQuery(this).text();
    if(file_text.length > 10){
        file_sub_text = file_text.substring(0,10);
        jQuery(this).text(file_sub_text+ "...");
    }
  });
```